# ChartJs has animation every time angular refresh the data

Tags: angular, chart.js

I've a variable number of charts to display with ChartJs.

So basically, I listen to an observable(that might changes the data or even the number of trends):

```
  <div *ngIf="adapterTrends | async as trends">
    <div *ngFor="let trend of trends" class="grid">
      <div class="col-2">{{ trend.label }}</div>
      <div class="col-2">{{ trend.lastValue }}</div>
      <div class="col-8">
        <p-chart type="line" [data]="trend" [options]="options"></p-chart>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

(by the way, it's expected that I've several line chart, and not one chart with several line)

My issue is that each time my data gets refreshed, I've the initial animation(which have the lines raising from the bottom). I've managed to disable totally the animation by setting the `options.animation` to false in my `[options]` object.

But is there a way to instead, animate the transition between the two set of data?

Comment: maybe it's worth trying out `ng2-charts` instead of your custom component `p-chart` (see https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-charts)

Comment: It's not custom, it's PrimeNg implementation. But I'm not sure it's related to the wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

In your chart component when the data changes you call `destroy()` on the chart instance and re create the entire chart. Instead of doing this you need to edit the values within the existing chart object and call `update()` on your chart instance.

```js
const newLabels = ["t", "a", "b"];
const newData = [2,3,4];

chartInstance.data.labels = newLabels;
chartInstance.data.datasets[0].data = newData;

chartInstance.update();
```

Comment: The issue is that the number of charts might change and I must be sure that the chart list is always up to date

Comment: I tried to make a smarter version, but since I bind the data of the `primeNg` `p-chart`, i'm not sure how I could call "refresh" on it?